# Where can i put json code from my rich card

Tags: json, seo, google-search, google-search-console

This is my Corporate Contacts rich card `JSON` code but I am getting error:

> "All values provided for
>   https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ must have the
>   same domain".

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "contactPoint": [{
                    "@type": "ContactPoint",
                    "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
                    "contactType": "customer service"
                  }]
}
</script>
```

and I am confused where to put this code in my site

Answer (score 0):

Put it as like a normal **`javascript`** code.

For example,

```
<head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
      "url": "http://www.example.com",
      "contactPoint": [{
                        "@type": "ContactPoint",
                        "telephone": "+1-401-555-1212",
                        "contactType": "customer service"
                      }]
    }
    </script>
</head>
```

You can also test you rich card in  **Google Structured Data Testing Tool**

> https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/